# jQuery validate length according to another elements value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a form, there is an input for ID that is required, it also needs to have 14 digits only if the nationality select is equal to a specific one, please take a look at the code

```
  jQuery("#msform").validate({
            groups: {
                dob: 'day month year'
            },
            rules: {
                full_name: "required",
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                passwordconfirm: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                nationality: "required",
                 id: {
                    required: true,
                    length:{
                        depends: function(element){
                        return ($("#id").val().length == 14 && $("#nationality").val()==61);
                        } 
                    } 
                },
                read: "required"
            },
            messages: {

            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") == "day" || element.attr("name") == "month") {
                    error.insertAfter(jQuery("#year"));
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }

        });
```

But this doesnt seem to work, when I move out of the ID input I see the below error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

Do you have an idea of how to implement this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
        nationality: "required",
        id: {
            required: true,
            minlength: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#nationality").val() == 61;
                },
                param: 14
            },
            maxlength: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    console.log($("#nationality").val())
                    return $("#nationality").val() == 61;
                },
                param: 14
            }
        }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wAADV/)

---

Or add a length rule

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('length', function (value, element, param) {
    var length = $.isArray(value) ? value.length : this.getLength($.trim(value), element);
    return this.optional(element) || length == param;
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter {0} characters."))
```

then

```
        nationality: "required",
        id: {
            required: true,
            length: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return $("#nationality").val() == 61;
                },
                param: 14
            }
        }
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9D3zF/)